# Blender 4.0 can't adjust material

Tags: materials

I have a problem with Blender 4.0. I have an .obj file exported from FreeCAD and I would like to add some material to it. But when I add the material to it (which is a picture of wooden texture), the pattern doesn't appear, on of the objects just become dark brown. If I do it on the basic cube, which appears when I start the program, everything is fine.
I attach a picture, where you can see the imported file (I only want to adjust the top object) in dark brown and the basic cube where the material appears perfectly.
Could you help me how to solve the problem?

Thank you for your help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). You probably need to UV unwrap your object again.